# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf with spark on hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to use SPARK as hive execution engine, but getting the below error. Spark 1.5.0 is installed and I am working with Hive 1.1.0 version with Hadoop 2.7.0 version.

`hive_emp` table is created as ORC format table in hive.

```
hive (Koushik)> insert into table hive_emp values (2,'Koushik',1);
Query ID = hduser_20150921072727_feba8363-258d-4d0b-8976-662e404bca88
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.HiveSparkClientFactory.generateSparkConf(HiveSparkClientFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.HiveSparkClientFactory.createHiveSparkClient(HiveSparkClientFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionImpl.open(SparkSessionImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionManagerImpl.getSession(SparkSessionManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkUtilities.getSparkSession(SparkUtilities.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask.execute(SparkTask.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1638)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:754)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 25 more
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. org/apache/spark/SparkConf
```

I also set the spark path and execution engine in hive shell.

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ spark-shell
    Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.5.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala> exit;
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
hduser@ubuntu:~$ hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/usr/lib/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
hive (default)> use Koushik;
OK
Time taken: 0.593 seconds
hive (Koushik)> set spark.home=/usr/local/src/spark;
```

I have also created a .hiverc as below

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/lib/hive/conf$ cat .hiverc
SET hive.cli.print.header=true;
set hive.cli.print.current.db=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
SET hbase.scan.cacheblock=0;
SET hbase.scan.cache=10000;
SET hbase.client.scanner.cache=10000;
SET hive.execution.engine=spark;
```

DEBUG mode error details given below:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/usr/lib/hive/conf/hive-log4j.properties
hive (default)> use Koushik;
OK
Time taken: 0.625 seconds
hive (Koushik)> set hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG
              > ;
hive (Koushik)> set hive.execution.engine=spark;
hive (Koushik)> desc hive_emp;
OK
col_name    data_type   comment
empid                   int                                         
empnm                   varchar(50)                                 
deptid                  int                                         
Time taken: 0.173 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
hive (Koushik)> select * from hive_emp;
OK
hive_emp.empid  hive_emp.empnm  hive_emp.deptid
Time taken: 1.689 seconds
hive (Koushik)> insert into table hive_emp values (2,'Koushik',1);
Query ID = hduser_20151015112525_c96a458b-34f8-42ac-ab11-52c32479a29a
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.addListener(Lorg/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.LocalHiveSparkClient.<init>(LocalHiveSparkClient.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.LocalHiveSparkClient.getInstance(LocalHiveSparkClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.HiveSparkClientFactory.createHiveSparkClient(HiveSparkClientFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionImpl.open(SparkSessionImpl.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionManagerImpl.getSession(SparkSessionManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkUtilities.getSparkSession(SparkUtilities.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask.execute(SparkTask.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1638)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:754)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:675)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.addListener(Lorg/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener;)V
hive (Koushik)>
```

I have executed the above insert twice and both the times it fails. Please find the hive.log which generated today.[hive.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Ed4jUfln0SNkhwNnVUMG9neGs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Where to check which spark version is compatible with hive 1.1.0 and hadoop 2.7.0

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Did you get a resolution yet ??

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is hive not able to find the spark assembly jar.

export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/src/spark or add the spark assembly jar in hive lib folder. This issue will be resolved.

Comment: got the error, after adding spark assembly in hive lib folder. `hive (Koushik)> insert into table hive_emp values (2,'Koushik',1);
Query ID = hduser_20151012230101_83f8304d-868a-4186-9380-416c1de40f45
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask`

Comment: Can you run hive in debug mode.. hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console and provide more details about the error

Comment: appended DEBUG mode error details in the with the actual post. Please see above.

Comment: I have also provided hive.log `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Ed4jUfln0SNkhwNnVUMG9neGs/view?usp=sharing` which generated today after executing the above insert twice.

Comment: I think In spark 2.0 (lib/jars) folder there is no spark-assembly jar so .. that u got that error..

Answer (score 1):

I too was facing the same issue on **`my Ubuntu 14.4 VitualBox`**. Here are the steps I have followed to fix:

1. **`hive> set spark.home=/usr/local/spark;`**
2. **`hive> set spark.master=local;`**
3. **`hive> SET hive.execution.engine=spark;`**
4. Added **`spark-assembly jar`** file as shown below:

   **`hive> ADD jar /usr/local/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar;`**

Comment: I followed the steps, but it didn't resolved the issue for me. Please find the [execution error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Ed4jUfln0SS3ZBMldhRHJHbHc/view?usp=sharing) and hive.log for this execution can be found [hive.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Ed4jUfln0SeHdsVTFrOHdfTWM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In addition to following steps described in the answer. Try running this, I forgot to add, export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/src/spark

Comment: does 'spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar' exist in /hive/lib folder?

Comment: with or without the jar placed in hive/lib folder I am getting error. When jar is placed then the error is `FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.addListener(Lorg/apache/spark/scheduler/SparkListener;)V`

Comment: when you followed the steps mentioned in the Answer, spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar was in /hive/lib folder or you followed the steps without having spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar' in /hive/lib?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93079/discussion-between-koushik-chandra-and-vinkal).

Comment: Where to check which spark version is compatible with hive 1.1.0 and hadoop 2.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Like you, I encountered the same problem when deploying hive on spark. Finally, after my research, it was found that because hive could not load spark jars, so I made the following changes to hive-env.sh.

Add in **hive-env.sh**:

//Pay attention to your spark path

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/module/spark-2.4.5-bin-without-hive
export SPARK_JARS=""
for jar in `ls $SPARK_HOME/jars`; do
    export SPARK_JARS=$SPARK_JARS:$SPARK_HOME/jars/$jar
done
export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=$SPARK_JARS
```

中文： 这就是你的hive启动时没加载到spark的jars,所以在**hive-env.sh**里配置一下环境就可以了。
**注意这里面的路径，我最下面的lzo你也可以不配，可以参考上面的这个配置（只是少了lzo）**

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/module/spark-2.4.5-bin-without-hive
export SPARK_JARS=""
for jar in `ls $SPARK_HOME/jars`; do
    export SPARK_JARS=$SPARK_JARS:$SPARK_HOME/jars/$jar
done
export HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=/opt/module/hadoop-3.1.3/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-lzo-0.4.21-SNAPSHOT.jar$SPARK_JARS
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue, and it was because the hive is not able to find spark files.  there is a well-detailed info step if you running spark on YARN. I followed Spark 2.3 on Yarn3.0 with Hive 3.1

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

```
To run with YARN mode (yarn-client or yarn-cluster), link the following jars to HIVE_HOME/lib.

    scala-library
    spark-core
    spark-network-common
```

Used below Steps:

- Get all the files for my version from `/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/jars`
- Copied all the above files from the spark directory to `/usr.hdp/current/hive-client`
- Create symlinks in hive dir files in the same dir without  and just .jar suffix.
- Restarted the hiveserver2 to load the new files.

It worked, and now Hive can load the files, and I can submit a hive query as Spark job on Yarn.  also, the files will have a version suffix at the end